# Python Unittest Inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, python-unittest

I have 2 classes, A and B.

```
class A (unittest.TestCase):
   #methods here

class B (A):
   #methods here
```

when i try and call self.assertEqual(1,1) in a method of class B, I get the error mentioned here: 
[Why do I get an AttributeError with Python3.4's `unittest` library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944798/why-do-i-get-an-attributeerror-with-python3-4s-unittest-library)
Yet if I call it in A, everything is fine. 
Does unittest not follow regular inheritance? Is there only a very specific way you can use it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python unit test with base and sub class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323455/python-unit-test-with-base-and-sub-class)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your example as such:

```
import unittest

class A(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_a(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)

class B(A):
    def test_b(self):
        self.assertEqual(2, 3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

and it worked, this is test result:

```
test_a (__main__.A) ... ok
test_a (__main__.B) ... ok
test_b (__main__.B) ... FAIL
```